# Knockout -> Bind element to Value of Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

In the following `select`, I'm binding an observable array.

```
<select id="selectProtocols" data-bind="options: optionsAvailable, optionsCaption:'Selecione...', optionsText: 'SimpleDescription', optionsValue:'???'"></select>
```

I believe it's easy to see that that the text of each option is a property "SimpleDescription", that works fine. What I need now is that the `value` of the `select` is the element itself!

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `optionsValue:$data` combined with `optionsAfterRender` function... it worked as expected with the object being passed around "in-natura"!

Comment: this might be true, but it's not directly because of `optionsValue:$data`.  Setting that doesn't work the way you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

> #### Note 2: Working with drop-down lists (i.e., `<select>` elements)
>
> Knockout has special support for drop-down lists (i.e., `<select>`
> elements). The value binding works in conjunction with the options
> binding to let you read and write values that are arbitrary JavaScript
> objects, not just string values. This is very useful if you want to
> let the user select from a set of model objects. For examples of this,
> see the options binding or for handling multi-select lists, see the
> documentation for the selectedOptions binding.
>
> http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply do not set the `optionsValue` attribute and Knockout will automatically store the selected object from the `observableArray` into the observable you have declared in the `value` attribute.

Deep within the bowels of Knockout is the following function:

```
function applyToObject(object, predicate, defaultValue) {
    var predicateType = typeof predicate;
    if (predicateType == "function")    // Given a function; run it against the data value
        return predicate(object);
    else if (predicateType == "string") // Given a string; treat it as a property name on the data value
        return object[predicate];
    else                                // Given no optionsText arg; use the data value itself
        return defaultValue;
}
```

If you do not set the `optionsValue` attribute then this function will fall into the bottom `else` statement which will return the current array item.

Comment: Seems like everyone's looking for data these days, eh?

Comment: This is actually incorrect, passing the `$data` object here doesn't do anything.  Even if it did, `$data` is the context in the current binding, which in this case is an object that includes `optionsAvailable`.

Comment: @Milimetric - You are correct. Passing `$data` does not do anything. In fact, the correct answer to the OP's question is simply to _not set_ the `optionsValue` attribute at all. My example does work, but not because of `$data`; it works because Knockout is ignoring `$data` and using the default which is the object in the array.

Comment: Correct.  You should update the text of your answer to reflect that.  I don't mind if you copy some from mine, or just make it say roughly the same thing.  If the OP accepts yours I'll remove mine.

Comment: Answer updated. I even included code from Knockout which explains why using `$data` was working. It was dumb luck. Since `$data` resolves as neither a function or a string (it is an object), Knockout defaults to the last `else` statement which is the equivalent of not declaring an `optionsValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `$data` to `optionsValue` does not make sense here, you have to read what `optionsValue` does [1].  It basically just sets the `value` attribute of the `<option>` elements under your `<select>`.  So you can't set it to the JS object that's being selected, you can only set it to text.

```
<select data-bind="
    options: optionsAvailable,
    optionsCaption: 'Selecione...',
    optionsText: 'SimpleDescription',
    optionsValue: 'SomeOtherPropertyThatEvaluatesToText',    
    value: selectedOption"></select>
```

The `value` binding should receive an observable that will be set to the selected JS object.  And, if you want, you can give `optionsValue` a function that takes this JS object and turns it into text, like this:

```
<select data-bind="
    options: optionsAvailable,
    optionsCaption: 'Selecione...',
    optionsText: 'SimpleDescription',
    optionsValue: JSON.stringify,    
    value: selectedOption"></select>
```

Here's a sample fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/43t9dzxt/1/

[1] http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html